# CSS Badge width and height

Tags: css, badge

I am creating some css badge. The problem is when number is 100 and bigger the last char get out of the badge?

Is it possible to create badge that will be bigger if number is bigger than 99?

Here is my code

**CSS**

```
.badge[data-badge]:after {
   content:attr(data-badge);
   font-size:.7em;
   background:rgba(48, 174, 227, 1);
   color:white;
   width:18px;
   height:18px;
   text-align:center;
   line-height:18px;
   border-radius:50%;
   box-shadow:0 0 1px #333;
   margin-top: 7px;
   float:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class='badge' data-badge='27'></span>
```

Here is working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kx5kow5m/

Comment: Did you try to set `width: auto;`?

Comment: Then when i have only example 1, than badge does not look nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the `width: auto` and add a `min-width: 18px`.

Also a padding would be good to add:

```
width: auto;
min-width: 18px;
paddding: 4px;
```

[Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx5kow5m/3/)

Comment: That will work for a three digit numbers. If OP needs to use four digits it will fail.

Comment: Looks fine to me. He hadn't said anything about that the bad should be a perfect circle.

Comment: Look at his comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set `width: auto` and add a padding if you need it.

```
width:auto;
padding: 2px;
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kx5kow5m/2/

Comment: Problem is now ok, but what if i have only 1, that bagde goes not round, try just say 1

Comment: @play2web Yeah, I just noticed that. Wait a second.